# why rails model gives an error after db reset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a rails model named as Student. it had 3 fields as roll_no, name, course. Student model is scaffold. then i reset the db with

```
rake db:reset
rake db:migration
```

in new schema.rb course field is removed and have added a new field as user_id but now when i try to add new student it gives

`undefined method error course for Student`

can anybody tell me the solution to this problem?

THANKS

Comment: Are you saying you're editing schema.rb manually? It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: yes, i edited it then used the above mentioned commands.

Comment: @user2975492 if you are changing the schema.rb manual when you do a rake db:reset it overrides and it sets it back to what the migration say it should be. you need to make a migration to create the Student table

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza thanks for your response. but i manually checked the db it is same as i edited the schema.rb file.

Comment: You should never edit schema.rb by hand. There's even a note at the top of that file that says this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Students table in your db

`rails generate migration CreateStudents roll_no:integer name:string, course:integer`